# How do I deploy a Flutter app to a single device without going through the app store?

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing an internal app for a company. I gave the end users a test version of the app by having them install Android Studio to their PC, then importing the project I was working on, installing the necessary dependencies, and running the app using:

```
flutter run
```

However, to give them an upgraded version later, we needed to do this whole process again. It's very time consuming. Is there a faster way to give them the latest version quickly? They only need to run the app, they won't be programming/debugging it. In the long run, we will be deploying the app over the network to all the target devices using some special software, but for now we just need a quick and easy way to push this out to one device over an internal network.

Comment: You need to provide an APK file. That is the file format that android devices use to install apps. Upload it somwhere or send it to your customer and let them install it. They might need to allow "apps from untrusted sources" on their android device to be able to install it. Just follow the documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: you can try to build an APK file and send it to them or you can upload to the play store as closed release with access to employees at the company by providing their emails so they are only invited to try the app.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase App Distribution can be a good option for both Android and iOS installation files and if you Apple Developer Account, you can directly upload the builds to TestFlight. And you can also manage users to access your app in both Firebase App Distribution and TestFlight

for more

Firebase App Distribution -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution

Apple Testflight -> https://developer.apple.com/testflight/